# What do I do with the stones in the Wending Wood?

Tags: dragon-age-origins-awakening

In the Wending Woods in DA:O:A, there is an arrangement of stones which go back to some sort of Tevinter enchantment. When you first arrive, there's a stone missing, but I've found the missing stone, put it in place, and played around with activating the other stones that light up to create the lines of fire. There's obviously some sort of puzzle to solve here, but I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do.

Can someone give me a gentle, non-spoilery hint as to what I need to do to solve this puzzle? Alternately, is there an in-game object that I need to get that will point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to extend the light so it travels through every stone

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [Dragon Age wiki:](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Wending_Wood_Stone_Puzzle)

> 1. To begin, select the lone 'Stone' marker. Clicking it will open three different 'Stone' options or directions that you can select to trace out your line of fire. Clicking on another stone traces a line to that 'Stone' and then gives you new options of 'Stones' to select to continue your line.
> 2. Of the 3 options, on either side or the outside, click the 'Stone' marker that is on the outside. Continue around clockwise connecting all of the outside 'Stone' markers. You should have ended at the marker next to the first outside marker you started with.
> 3. Now, move inward and click on the 'Stone' marker on the middle ring. Continue back, counter-clockwise around the middle ring until you are next to the starting stone.
> 4. Click on the 'Stone' marker on the innermost ring. Continue around clockwise again until you finish hitting each stone in that ring. You should be next to the last open 'Stone' marker left on the middle ring.
> 5. Last but not least, select that open marker on the middle ring and finish your continuous line of magic fire by clicking back on the beginning starting stone. You should have connected every 'Stone' completing the puzzle.